# ¿Por qué no avanza al siguiente for?

Tags: c++, c

Tengo el siguiente código el cual solo queda en el primer for, y no avanza al siguiente

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Cant_Cocineros; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {  // Proceso hijo         
            CocinarAlbondigas(&cocineros[i], &cantina, &banderaMostrador, &platosCocinados);
            exit(0);
        }   
    }

     for (int i = 0; i < Cant_Mozos; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            ServirPlatos(&Mozos[i], &cantina, &banderaMozo);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
```

en la funcion CocinarAlbondigas activo una bandera para que se active el meodo del mozo.
pero el for en el que se crean los procesos de los mozos nunca llega a activarse, como hago para que salga del primer for y avance al for en el que están los mozos?

Quiero que avance del for de procesos de cocineros, y que se logre ejecutar la funcion ServirPlatos en el for de mozos

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: ¿Es código C o C++?

Comment: está en código C, pero tiene algunas dependencias de C++

Comment: ¿Estas seguro de que el segundo for no se ejecuta?, porque no veo como... Haz un poco del viejo _print debugging_ y pon `printf` en ese segundo for a ver que pasa... Nota que deberías comprobar siempre que el fork tiene éxito (pip != -1 en el padre. Parece como si estuvieras usando un patrón productor-consumidor, yo me decantaría por que el problema esta en el tema peliagudo de la concurrencia, la coordinación/sincronización entre esos subprocesos... pero no tenemos esa información en el código que muestras.

Comment: Para eso que mencionas a lo último, tengo esta parte de código que ahora que mencionas , parece estar mal : 

// Esperar a que algunos procesos finalicen
    for (int i = 0; i < Cant_Cocineros + Cant_Mozos; i++) {
        waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
    }

Comment: `waitpid(-1, ...)` esperara a que termine cualquiera de los subprocesos, pero si lo ejecutas una vez por cada subproceso  creeado consecutivamente en un loop  en esencia estas haciendo que el padre espere a  que terminen todos... Dependiendo de donde estés haciendo eso puedes estar efectivamente bloqueando la ejecución.